# Node API design and re-using code

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, abstract

My API has three endpoints: `articles`, `websites`, and `users`. Each `article` is associated with a `website`. A `user` can also share `articles`.

In my API, I have just created an endpoint at `/website/:id/articles`. This will query the database for `articles` associated with the given `website`. It then performs some manipulation on the data for each article based on who is talking to the API ("has the user shared this article?", for example).

I am now moving on to create a similar endpoint at `/users/:id/shared-articles`. The database query for this is slightly different, **but the manipulation I want to perform on the articles data following the query is the same as before**.

Here is some pseudo code for the former endpoint:

```
router.get('/websites/:id/articles', function (req, res) {
  articleService.find({ websiteId: req.params.id }, function (error, foundArticles) {

    async.waterfall([
      function (cb) {
        // Manipulate foundArticles…
        cb(null, manipulatedArticles)
      },
      function (articles, cb) {
        // Manipulate articles some more…
        cb(null, manipulatedArticles)
      },
    ], function (error, articles) {
      if (error) {
        return res.json(error, 400)
      }

      res.json(articles)
    })
  })
})
```

To create my new endpoint, `/users/:id/shared-articles`, I could abstract the manipulation tasks into a function that can be shared by both of my endpoints (the waterfall seen above), reducing code repetition.

```
router.get('/websites/:id/articles', function (req, res) {
  articleService.find({ websiteId: req.params.id }, function (error, foundArticles) {
    manipulateArticles(foundArticles, function (articles) {
      if (error) {
        return res.json(error, 400)
      }

      res.json(articles)
    })
  })
})

router.get('/users/:id/shared-articles', function (req, res) {
  shareActionService.find({ userId: req.params.id }, function (error, foundShareActions) {
    var sharedArticleIds = { _id: { $in: _.pluck(foundShareActions, 'sharedArticleId') } }

    articleService.find(sharedArticleIds, function (error, foundArticles) {
      manipulateArticles(foundArticles, function (articles) {
        if (error) {
          return res.json(error, 400)
        }

        res.json(articles)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

However, I figured that this sort of code re-use problem must be common when designing APIs in Node, and I would like to know if there is an obviously better solution that I am missing here.

One idea I had would be to have all article sub-resources (such as `/users/:id/shared-articles` or `/websites/:id/links`) talk to the `/links` API internally, which itself would deal with the manipulation I mention above. The problem then is that I would have to make `/links` very verbose in the query headers/parameters it needs, in order to allow for the different database queries needed (such as those by the two sub-resource endpoints demonstrated here).

Is there a better solution/abstraction here?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "service" layer. Abstract the link manipulation into a completely separate file and call it from each of the routes.

Create a service/links.js:

```
module.exports = {
    manipulateLinks: function (response) {
        // Manipulate code
        return response
    }
}
```

Then in you routes, call the function:

```
var linkservice = require('../service/links')
var response = linkservice.manipulateLinks(response)
```

Comment: That is what I suggested in my original post. I would like to know if there are better ways of handling this.

Comment: No, it's pretty simple abstraction. Anything more than this would be weird.